# In C language how to calculate the term number of infinite series where we get pi=3.14, pi=3.141,pi=3.1415 and finally pi=3.14159?

Tags: c, while-loop, break, pi, approximation

The question is: Calculate the value of π from the infinite series. Print a table that
shows the value of π approximated by one term of this series, by two terms, by three terms,
and so on. How many terms of this series do you have to use before you first get 3.14?
3.141? 3.1415? 3.14159?

```
int n = 2;
double sum,
 pi = 4,
    den;

printf("Calculating the value of pi.\n");
while (pi != 3.140000) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        den = (2 * n) - 1;
        sum = (4.0 / den);
        pi = pi - sum;
    }
    else {
        den = (2 * n) - 1;
        sum = (4.0 / den);
        pi = pi + sum;
    }
    pi = (round(pi * 100)) / 100;
    printf("pi=%lf\n", pi);
    if (pi == 3.140000) {
        break;
    }
    n = n + 1;
}

printf("The number of terms to get pi=3.14 is %d.\n", n - 2);
```

This code works, and shows that we would get 3.14 at term 30 but when I repeat this code to get the term numbers where pi=3.141,pi=3.1415 and pi=3.14159, the code doesn't work and on execution just shows black screen with the statement, Calculating the value of pi.[This is not the exact output I want but kind of. Actually I want that the table should print till I get 3.14,then I should get the statement showing the term number where I get 3.14, the the table starts from where I left and as soon as I get 3.141,the statement showing the term number where I get 3.141 prints and so on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5M7h.jpg)
Please help me in this regard.(In C language)
(I have to do this without using prec ,trunc or some other features as I am not allowed)

Edit: I did this:

```
int
main()
{
    int n = 2,
        x = 2,
        y = 2,
        z = 2;
    double sum,
     pi = 4;

    printf("Calculating the value of pi.\n");
    while (pi != 3.140000) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi - sum;
        }
        else {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi + sum;
        }
        pi = (round(pi * 100)) / 100;
        if (pi == 3.140000) {
            break;
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    while (pi != 3.141000) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi - sum;
        }
        else {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi + sum;
        }
        pi = (round(pi * 100)) / 100;
        if (pi == 3.141000) {
            break;
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    while (pi != 3.141500) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi - sum;
        }
        else {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi + sum;
        }
        pi = (round(pi * 100)) / 100;
        if (pi == 3.141500) {
            break;
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    while (pi != 3.141590) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi - sum;
        }
        else {
            sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
            pi = pi + sum;
        }
        pi = (round(pi * 100)) / 100;
        if (pi == 3.141590) {
            break;
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    printf("The number of terms to get pi=3.14 is %d.\n", n - 2);
    printf("The number of terms to get pi=3.141 is %d.\n", n - 2);
    printf("The number of terms to get pi=3.1415 is %d.\n", n - 2);
    printf("The number of terms to get pi=3.14159 is %d.\n", n - 2);
}
```

but screen shows no output.

Comment: Time ot drop into a debugger and find out what's going on.

Comment: `if(pi==3.140000){` - this is highly unlikely to ever become true in any context.

Comment: You should not use `==` on floating point numbers. You can check if the delta is lower than a given value, for example replace `pi == 3.14` with something like `pi - 3.14 < 1e-2`.

Comment: What @Hugal31 said but make sure to check both sides `pi - 3.14 < 1e-2 && 3.14 - pi < 1e-2` so that you're actually close, not just smaller.

Comment: @cafce25 Yes you're right. You can also use fabs.

Answer (score 2):

`while ( pi != 3.140000 )` requires that you know the answer already. Why would you be calculating `pi` if you did?

What you should use instead is something like

```c
double precision = 0.01;
double pi = 4;
while ( 1 ) {
   double previous_pi = 4;

   # Refine the value of `pi` here...

   if ( fabs( previous_pi - pi ) < precision / 2 )
      break;
}
```

And this gives us the answer to your question. Just vary `0.01` to get different precisions.

Comment: Thanks, but can't use  (fabs(previous...) feature because I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: Think for two seconds. It's easy to find the absolute value of a number without using `fabs`. `while ( 1 ) { double delta = previous_pi - pi; if ( delta < 0 ) delta = -delta; if ( delta < 0.01 ) break; ... }`

Comment: Agree about `fabs( previous_pi - pi )`, but the threshold should be `0.01/2` to have the chance that printing rounds to the same output.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. I had a nagging feeling it wasn't quite right, but I couldn't come up with the correct tolerance.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the apparent never ending process when you are looking for a value such as "3.14100" is that you need to up your rounding precision for more decimal places.  In your code this statement is tripping you up.

```
pi=(round(pi*100))/100;
```

This statement never allows the code to review the values with a precision greater than two decimal places.

To make your code a bit more robust, following is a tweaked version of your code with some #define statements to identify the value being queried along with the precision to the right of the decimal place desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define check 3.14100
#define precision 1000

int main()
{
    int n=2;
    double sum,pi=4.000000,den;

    printf("Calculating the value of pi.\n");
    while(pi != check)
    {
        if(n%2==0)
        {
            den=(2*n)-1;
            sum=(4.0/den);
            pi=pi-sum;
        }
        else
        {
            den=(2*n)-1;
            sum=(4.0/den);
            pi=pi+sum;
        }
        pi=(round(pi*precision))/precision; /* Provide enough precision */
        printf("pi=%lf\n",pi);
        if(pi == check)
        {
            break;
        }
        n=n+1;
    }
    printf("The number of terms to get pi= %f is %d.\n", check, n-2);

    return 0;
}
```

The main takeaway is the precision multiplier/divisor value to be used.

When testing that out with a value of "3.14100", following is the last few output lines on the terminal.

```
pi=3.142000
pi=3.137000
pi=3.141000
The number of terms to get pi= 3.141000 is 443.
```

I utilized fixed #define statements, but you might perform some positional checking of a your test value to come up with a more flexible method of determining the precision value needed.

Give that a try to see if that it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Thanks, this is working but it gives only single statement at the end that pi =3.141 at 443. I want the screen to show table till i get 3.14, after that it would be written that at 30 we get this. Then the table continues till I get 3.141 and   statement showing iteration number at which i get 3.141.Again table continues till I get 3.1415 and statement is printed. Kindly provide code for this situation.

Comment: pi = 2.666667
pi = 3.466667
pi = 2.895238
...
pi = 3.150140
pi = 3.133118
pi = 3.149996
Found 3.14 at iteration 117
...
pi = 3.141000
pi = 3.142185
pi = 3.141000
Found 3.141 at iteration 1686
THIS IS THE OUTPUT I WANT. I found it on the same form but the problem is it's code contained prec and trun which I couldn't use.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than limit to `pi != 3.14xxx`, use a tolerance about the value.

```
fabs(pi - pi_Appoximate) >= 0.5 / limit
```

With just a few changes to OP's code, iterate rather than replicate code with increasing power-of-ten.

```
int main(void) {
  printf("Calculating the value of pi.\n");
  char *pi_string = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795";
  for (unsigned i = 4; i<17; i++) {
    char buf[i + 1];
    buf[0] = '\0';
    double pi_Appoximate = atof(strncat(buf, pi_string, i));
    double limit = pow(10, i - 1);
    unsigned n = 2;
    double sum;
    double pi = 4;
    printf("i:%2u limit:%e ~pi:%.*g", i, limit, i, pi_Appoximate);
    fflush(stdout);
    while (fabs(pi - pi_Appoximate) >= 0.5 / limit) {
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
        sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
        pi = pi - sum;
      } else {
        sum = (4.0 / ((2 * n) - 1));
        pi = pi + sum;
      }
      pi = (round(pi * limit)) / limit;
      n = n + 1;
    }
    printf(" pi:%.*g n:%u\n", i, pi, n);
  }
  puts(pi_string);
}
```

Output

```
Calculating the value of pi.
i: 4 limit:1.000000e+03 ~pi:3.14 pi:3.14 n:802
i: 5 limit:1.000000e+04 ~pi:3.141 pi:3.141 n:1145
i: 6 limit:1.000000e+05 ~pi:3.1415 pi:3.1415 n:36366
i: 7 limit:1.000000e+06 ~pi:3.14159 pi:3.14159 n:72729
i: 8 limit:1.000000e+07 ~pi:3.141592 pi:3.141592 n:1379312
i: 9 limit:1.000000e+08 ~pi:3.1415926 pi:3.1415926 n:2649009
i:10 limit:1.000000e+09 ~pi:3.14159265 pi:3.14159265 n:7476638
i:11 limit:1.000000e+10 ~pi:3.141592653 pi:3.141592653 n:40363271
i:12 limit:1.000000e+11 ~pi:3.1415926535 pi:3.1415926535 n:58402689
i:13 limit:1.000000e+12 ~pi:3.14159265358 pi:3.14159265358 n:62874301
i:14 limit:1.000000e+13 ~pi:3.141592653589 pi:3.141592653589 n:68508285
i:15 limit:1.000000e+14 ~pi:3.1415926535897 pi:3.1415926535897 n:53634827
i:16 limit:1.000000e+15 ~pi:3.14159265358979 pi:3.14159265358979 n:59359529
3.1415926535897932384626433832795
```

As `double` math precision is about 15-17 decimal digits, little need to go further.